# Jenkins Global Pipleline Library - how to copy a directory from resources dir to workspace?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there an environment variable that defines the global lib root so I can just shell out and cp a dir from the global pipeline library's resources dir? I don't want to read a single file, I want to copy an entire dir and it's files.

Unfortunately it seems like this may not be possible - if not, how would you do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you have many files that you want to put on disk, but not list in your code, you can use the `git` step to check out a repository (new name for *folder*). In doubt, check out your pipeline repository itself.